# Json Record boundary using Json Schema

Tags: java, json, hadoop

Basically I am working on building a CustomInput Format in hadoop to reading Json Input files (Java).My understanding is json files have multiple formats. 
Some documents start with an array ("{") and some documents would start with record identifier. I am just thinking to build something which can identify a record boundary using a schema file that tells us how to read a json document or which means where does a record begin. As of now validating the entire json document is not the case for me. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Arrays start and end with `[...]`. Objects start and end with `{...}`. Are you saying that documents that contain an array should be treated as multiple records, and documents with only one object should be treated as one record?

Comment: No.  I am not saying that. The point is how to interpret a record. I meant some records does not have record identifier for document and some may have. like id {} .Assuming the system does not how the json files would be.  So I need to think about a logic to identify the record layout and process each json record.